# SQL Server 2014 Percentage Dramas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to run a query that will return the percentage of people who live within a certain distance of a HQ location (straight line as the crow flies).

The two main parts to my query work fine, ie working out a number of Clients within 5 miles and counting the number of all clients but an hour of messing around with brackets and a further hour searching forums has left me begging for help.

```
Select
((
(Select COUNT (*) FROM t_address WHERE (SQUARE(Coord_X) + SQUARE(Coord_Y) <= SQUARE (5)))
/
(Select Count (*) FROM t_address)
)*100) AS "% Clients Within 5 Miles"
```

Comment: And what is the problem? The idea behind the query looks OK. Do you get an error message? Do you get incorrect result?

Comment: i get results of 97 and 500 for the two parts but when I merge the two together i get ) results

Comment: It would help if you posted your table definition and sample data.  OR if you can setup a SQLFiddle, that would be even better.

Comment: Convert your numbers to floats. It is converting to integers and 19 / 500 = 0 when doing integer math.

Comment: @Rabbit Thanks, I just looked this up, I guess every days a school day.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the simpler version of:

```
select avg(case when SQUARE(Coord_X) + SQUARE(Coord_Y) <= SQUARE(5) 
                then 100.0
                else 0
           end) as ClientsWithin5Miles
from t_address;
```

Comment: Wow, how come this seems so obvious now.  Best solution.

Comment: completely agree, thanks to everyone who helped on the other version, I genuinely learnt alot from that but i'm gonna have to go with this version

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on it using a `case` statement:

```
select 100 * sum(case when SQUARE(Coord_X) + SQUARE(Coord_Y) <= SQUARE(5) 
                then 1 
                else 0
           end) / cast(count(*) as decimal(10,2))  as ClientsWithin5Miles
from t_address
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edd8f/4)

Comment: thanks, I tried this but still get 0 results when i should be getting 19%

Comment: why did the integers have to be turned into decimal?

Comment: Thanks again. for explaining, I will do better next time

Comment: @sgeddes That's actually incorrect. The reason is because the SUM (which is just adding 1) returns an integer and the COUNT returns an integer. The reason 100 * sum... works is because of the order in which the equation is evaluated. It does 100 * sum... (which is 300 in your fiddle) then divides it by 4. If you do sum... * 100 you'll get 0 because it will do 3/4 (which is 0 unless one is cast to decimal) then multiply that by 100.

Comment: @sgeddes You could do sum(1.0 or 0) and return a decimal. The problem is you're summing 1 or 0 (not the column itself) which are both integers so the sum returns an integer.

Comment: @sgeddes, That's because 300 / 4 divides evenly into an integer (remember, it evaluates 100 * the first integer first). If you were to tweak it slightly, like in the following fiddle, it would return the wrong value. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6ca3/1 - 83 instead of 83.3333

Comment: @ZLK -- Wow, I didn't notice that (again, great explanation). Thanks!